# Send range from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

My code is to send a range from one workbook to another.

It gives me error 9.

```vb
Sub SendInfoToDifferentWorkBook()
Dim LastRowA As Integer
Dim SKU As Range

LastRowA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set SKU = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(LastRowA, "A"))

Workbooks("Origin WB".xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").SKU.Copy Workbooks("Destiny WB.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: That code  would never run at all, as posted. You have an extra quote in the middle of the workbook name. Also SKU is a range variable and doesn't require `Workbooks("Origin WB.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").` in front of it at that point - but you probably should specify that when setting the variable initially.

Comment: Two things: your lines `LastRowA = ...` and `Set SKU = ...` use unqualified range references,  which refer to the Active Workbook/Worksheet.   Quality all range  references to a Workbook and Worksheet to ensure you get the ranges you expect. And `Workbooks("Origin WB".xlsm")` probably should  be `Workbooks("Origin WB.xlsm")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your first Workbooks() you got 3 times ", it could come from here. regarding to the second Workbooks("Destiny WB.xlsx") you can try to set the " in the same way. hope it helped you